# How to get request headers using Owin Self Host Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

I have ported an existing web api project - which has been run using IIS - to OWIN (selfhosted). I´m using dependency injection (unity) and have implemented a service which needs some information from the current request´s header (i.e. `var x = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["xxx"]`).

Since `HttpContext` is not available in OWIN (which makes sense) - how can I get the current request? Please keep in mind that I do need this information inside an injected service (not inside a controller and an OWIN middleware module - owincontext).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? The answer of getting the headers in the controller does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller should inherit from `ApiController`, which has a `Request` property that will be populated for each request. So from within your controller action just use `Request.Headers[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sample class like below

```
public class HeaderParser
{

    IDictionary<string, object>  _requestContext;
    IDictionary<string, string[]> _headers;
    public HeaderParser(IDictionary<string, object> requestContext)
    {
        _requestContext = requestContext;
        _headers = requestContext["owin.RequestHeaders"] as IDictionary<string, string[]>;
    }
    public string GetEmployeeNoFromHeader()
    {
        if (_headers != null && _headers.ContainsKey("X-EmployeeNo") && _headers["X-EmployeeNo"] != null && _headers["X-EmployeeNo"].Length > 0)
        {
            return _headers["X-EmployeeNo"][0];
        }
        else
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            response.Content = new StringContent("EMPLOYEE NO NOT AVAILABLE IN REQUEST");
            throw new HttpResponseException(response);
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller something like below should work

```
var owincontext = request.GetOwinContext().Environment;
```

var headerParser= new HeaderParser(owincontext);
headerParser.GetEmployeeNoFromHeader()

What we have done is we have implemented interface IHttpControllerActivator.Create like below, so it runs for all controller class, The controller is generated by dependency injection windsor castle

```
public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType)
    {
       var owincontext = request.GetOwinContext().Environment;

       var headerParser= new HeaderParser(owincontext);
       var logger = _dpendencyManager.Resolve(typeof(IPOSLogger)) as IPOSLogger;
       var executionContext = new ExecutionContext(logger, owincontext,headerParser.GetEmployeeNoFromHeader());
       var controller =
           (IHttpController)_dpendencyManager.Resolve(controllerType, new { context = executionContext });
       //var controller =
       //  (IHttpController)_dpendencyManager.Resolve(controllerType);
       request.RegisterForDispose(
           new Release(
               () => _dpendencyManager.Release(controller)));

        return controller;
    }
```